# How to retrieve data of <li> element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I currently have a this menu on the navbar

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="mainnav" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Price</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now I want to get all of the li (including its html tag) to create another menu. How can I achieve this with jQuery.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that are most helpful to this question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$("#main-nav ul").html()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get HTML. You may use [**`.clone()`**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [**`.appendTo()`**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) jquery methods to achieve it efficiently.

**jQuery**

```
$('#main-nav').find('ul').clone().appendTo($(selector)); // selector = Where you want to add cloned ul content
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lpylq)

Comment: +1 I like this one better than mine haha. But just to make your example clearer, you could append the clone to another element :) and not `main-nav` again.

Comment: Thanks, It's just an idea actually. That's why I also included reference links for those methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** to get the html content of your list then use **[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** to append this list to another `ul`:

```
$('#second-nav ul').append($('#main-nav ul').html());
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzLyS/)**